# Extracting certain position within nested dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

this is a dummy version of what a function returns. I would like to know how to extract

`'the.email@addresi.want'`  and `'Nextstringiwant` from:

```
{'blah': {'blah1': 'the.email@addresi.want', 'blah2': 'Nextstringiwant'}, 'blah3': {'-note-': 'blah4', 'blah5': 'blah6', 'blah7': 'blah@bleble.blah', 'blah8': 'blah9'}}
```

I honestly don't understand the purpose for `{}` brackets very well, or how to work with it. I cannot change the function that returns this. Please help me, i'm lost. My gut tells me that I should convert this into a normal list and just get the desired position within that list, but it returns this error.

My code:

```
brackets = function().split(sep=':')
brackets.to_list()
email=brackets[2]
string=brackets[3]
```

The error:

```
brackets = creds.split(sep=':')
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'split'
```

Note: 
This is exactly how the function returns the `{}`  `list`, I only changed the values for simplicity sake.

I would really appreciate

Comment: `{}` are used to create/denote dictionary objects in Python. I think it would help to read into these more to understand how to get what you want. Briefly, they contain key-value pairs that are indexed by the key. Here's some [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) that might be useful.

Comment: Take a look https://www.learnpython.org/en/Dictionaries Hope it helps

Comment: Okay thanx so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
mydict = {
    'blah': {'blah1': 'the.email@addresi.want', 
             'blah2': 'Nextstringiwant'}, 
    'blah3': {'-note-': 'blah4', 
              'blah5': 'blah6', 
              'blah7': 
              'blah@bleble.blah', 
              'blah8': 'blah9'}
}

[k_ for k_ in mydict.get("blah", dict()).values()]
```

Output:

```
['the.email@addresi.want', 'Nextstringiwant']
```

Answer (score 2):

As the error message indicates, `split` is an attribute/method for a **string**, not for a dictionary.

Your function returns a Python **dictionary**.

Given your function is called `function`, you can access the values like this:

```
result = function()

email_address = result["blah"]["blah1"]  # this will be 'the.email@addresi.want'

next_string = result["blah"]["blah2"]  # this will be 'Nextstringiwant'
```

You can get further information on Python dictionaries on this site:
https://realpython.com/python-dicts/

Answer (score -2):

`{}` mean json object in Python.
if that function return is string, you should use Json module of python to convert it to json object and access its properties. For example:

```
import json
obj = json.loads(str_above)
print (obj.blah.blah1)
print (obj.blah.blah2)
```

Comment: `{}` is a `dict`. json *can* be represented like that, but it's not the case.